# How can I set Discord to always show a custom status message?

Tags: discord

I've been looking for the solution to this for a while and even tried my own. I'm trying to change Discord to always show my custom message, but when I play games like Rocket league and LoL the game's name goes over my message.

Those are verified games so I can't change the name for those, I also can't change the file now for league because then the client won't work and idk what other files to change if I do change that. If you could help I would appreciate it but seems like there's no solution.

Comment: It's not a duplicate of that question. I want a custom message to show without having other games I open override that custom message. For example if I were trying to have a custom message that says "Playing in the clouds" showing all the time it wouldn't work because the second I launch another game like osu or league it overrides that custom status message when I wouldn't like it to.

Comment: Voted to reopen. The answer on the linked question shows how to have no status message, regardless of what you're playing. This question is asking how to have a custom status, regardless of what you're playing.

Answer (score 4):

Discord by default will show what game you're playing because it keeps a database of common game executables and their corresponding games (i.e., if there's a program running on your computer called "LeagueOfLegends.exe", Discord knows to write "Playing League of Legends" as your status). However, if you've ever played a more obscure game, you may notice that Discord does not automatically update your status at all. This is because Discord does not recognize the game's executable, or it doesn't have the game title in the database.

You are able to tell Discord which programs are "games" and what those game names are. The process is detailed on [their blog](https://blog.discordapp.com/all-your-game-are-detection-fd06b1683137). Basically, while a program is running, you can select it from within Discord and give the executable a name. Then, whenever that program is running, Discord will update your status message.

This only works with games that are not already verified. Most popular games are already recognized, so you won't be able to customize a League of Legends message. However, it sounds like you want a custom message for when you're not playing games. If that's the case, there's a kind of hack to work around that - just add Notepad (the windows text editor) or some other lightweight program to Discord's list of "games", then edit it's name to your status. Whenever you want to display that status, just open Notepad.

Answer (score 4):

Since October 25, 2019, you can set a custom status message by clicking your profile picture and selecting "Set a custom status":

[image]

A window will be shown asking for your message and after how much time do you want to remove the custom status message:

[image]

This will override the current status message for your game, but they can always check what you are playing by clicking your user:

[image]
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I found Discord recognizes itself as a game, so if you add that and rename it, it will *always* be on.

[image: example]